# Can you add translation for all modules in 1 file

Tags: localisation, magento2.4.4

Is it possible to translate every lines from any modules in one file?

I pulled `bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o` directly in root and got all the lines with their locations ex: ,module,Magento_OfflineShipping

Ideally, I would pull the lines I need, create a separate file and add translations I need. We already have a dictionary in /app/i18n/fr_ca but adding lines to this file does not seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, best way to translate terms from storefront theme. For example, theme name in your project is "**ExampleCorp_orange**" then go to

```
app/design/frontend/ExampleCorp/orange/i18n/fr_ca.csv
```

And add those terms in above file along with translation. Like this:

```
"Add to Cart", "Ajouter au chariot"
"Add to Compare", "ajouter pour comparer"
"Add to Wish List", "Ajouter à la liste de souhaits"
```

then, Run the deploy command to get localization changes:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Happy coding!